# Inserting and modifying ListView items

Tags: c, listview, winapi

I am learning about the ListView control, and I want to make sure that I got this right:

- If I want to insert a new Item I would use the `LVM_INSERTITEM`
  message, and if I want to insert a new Subitem I would use the
  `LVM_SETITEM` message.
- However, if I want to modify an existing Item or Subitem, I would use
  the `LVM_SETITEM` message (so in this case the `LVM_SETITEM` message
  also works for the Item).

Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

According to the *Remarks* section of

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761107(v=vs.85).aspx

you are correct.

More detailed info:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761186(v=vs.85).aspx